# AsyncTask: Using web services & threads

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask on button click to refresh the screen. Following is the sequence of events that happen on btn click

1. progress dialog shows up
2. The doInBackground is called and thread is initialized which calls a web service. The web service fetches/uploads data.    A pass/fail flag is set once the web service is called.

My problem is the onPostExecute is never called and therefore the screen is never refreshed.
And secondly by the time the data is downloaded and the web service sets the flag my code has already hit return stmt in doInBackground.

Question is how do i stop execution in my asynctask so that the web service is done downloading/uploading the data and finally execute onPostexecute.

FYI
I also get the following warning in eclipse

> The method onPostExecute(boolean) from
>   the type
>   Screen.ConnectWebService is
>   never used locally

```
private class ConnectWebService extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean>
        {
            private final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(screen.this);

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pd.show(Screen.this, "Sync", "Sync in progress",true,false);
            }


            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... unused) {

                if (SyncInProgress == false)
                {

                    CallWSThread();//creates thread which  calls web service
                }
                        Log.d("doInBackground","doInBackground");
                return SyncStatus;
            }

            protected Void onPostExecute(boolean result)
            {   

                pd.dismiss();
                if (result==true) drawRadioButtons();

                 return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Just remove your methods and let eclipse auto generate them. It'll create them with the right input parameters, modifiers and override notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
protected Void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
```

Comment: Yep, that does fix the problem..partly, onPostExecute() does get called now. But still cant figure out how stop the execution till all the download is complete and then call onPostExecute()

Comment: do you have to create a separate thread to call the WS?  Can you just synchronously access it in the doInBackground method?

Comment: Tried doing it ...but by the time data is downloaded from the server it has already moved on to `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

As djg noted, you have a typo in your method declaration. You can avoid these kinds of mistakes by using the annotation [@Override](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) when you're implementing methods from a super class.