# Android: Cannot dismiss progressdialog

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I am trying to dismiss a progress dialog but it doesnt seem to work for some reason. Any suggestions why is it so??
The progress dialog is initialized on button click and shows the dialog. The syncbutton method calls a thread which sends an empty message

thanks

> mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);//from thread

Code for button click

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    pd = new ProgressDialog(Screen.this);
                    pd.setCancelable(true);
                    ProgressDialog.show(Screen.this, "Sync", "Sync in progress",true,false);
                    SyncButton();

                }
            });
```

Code for message handler which should dismiss the progressbar

```
mHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    Log.d("Handler","handler");
                    if (Screen==true){
                        if (pd !=null)
                        { 
                            pd.cancel();
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Log.d("HANDLER", "called dismiss");
                        } 


                    }
                }

            };
```

PS: I did try using asynctask but was having problems with it. Thats why took this approach. I had posted that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915501/asynctask-using-web-services-threads/5915598#5915598)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looke like you are creating one progress dialog here:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(Screen.this);
pd.setCancelable(true);
```

That one isn't displayed. You create and display another one:

```
ProgressDialog.show(Screen.this, "Sync", "Sync in progress",true,false);
```

Remove the two first lines, and change your other line to:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(Screen.this, "Sync", "Sync in progress",true,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing the pd you created, you are showing a new one.

build pd

```
pd.setTitle("Sync");
pd.setMessage("Sync in progress");
```

then use

```
pd.show();
```